# Sequential selection multi select Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins pipeline with a choice parameter, multi select field, like:

```
[
  $class: 'ChoiceParameter',
  choiceType: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT',
  filterLength: 1,
  filterable: true,
  name: 'LIST',
  script: [
    $class: 'GroovyScript',
    fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: true, script: 'return[]'],
    script: [
      classpath: [],
      sandbox: true,
      script: 'return ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"]'
    ]
  ]
],......
```

Then, in the running stage I'm using the values parametrized, like:

```
Itm1='''+params.LIST.split(',')[0]+''' \
Itm2='''+params.LIST.split(',')[1]+''' \
...
```

The problem is that this kind of setup will take all choosen values ordered by name and it doesn't matter which one you selected first, second and so forth. My goal is to have them sequentially ordered - e.g.: item3 is selected first, then it will be element 0, item1 is second, then it will be element 1 and etc...

Comment: If the order of selection is matter you need more complex logic, I suggest you to use `choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML',` and to count how many options are already selected when one of them is clicked and then attach the result as an hidden value to the html selection field. After that you can parse the selection value and it's index and you will get something like `["Item1" : 0, "item3" : 2]...` Consider a complex implementation maybe it's better to change the idea and take the order as well from the user.